# Need Help adding links to Navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help adding links to the Nav bar, and I would also like to make "Home" like the other buttons so that they turn. I would be happy just adding links though, I am just learning how to code.

```
<HTML>
<ul class="snip1526">
  <li class="current"><a href="#" data-hover="Home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-hover="About Us">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-hover="Blog">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-hover="Services">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-hover="Products">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-hover="Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<HTML>

<style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans);
.snip1526 {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.snip1526 *,
.snip1526 *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

.snip1526 li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0.5em 0.6em;
  -webkit-perspective: 50em;
  perspective: 50em;
}

.snip1526 a {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  line-height: 2.2em;
  padding: 0 1.4em;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: #667273;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.snip1526 a:after {
  background-color: #5c122e;
  color: transparent;
  content: attr(data-hover);
  top: 0%;
  line-height: 2.2em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%) rotateY(90deg);
  transform: translateX(0%) rotateY(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

.snip1526 li:hover a,
.snip1526 li.current a {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%) rotateY(-90deg);
  transform: translate(-50%) rotateY(-90deg);
  background-color: #1e2222;
  color: transparent;
}

.snip1526 li:hover a:after,
.snip1526 li.current a:after {
  background-color: #b12358;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Demo purposes only */
body {
  background-color: #212121;
  padding: 40px 0;
}
</style>

<script>
$(".hover").mouseleave(
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);

</script>
```

Comment: If you're just learning Webdevelopment CSS-Transitions and Animations might be a little to much atm. As stated in the answers you add links to an anchor-tag by inserting it into the `href=""` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add links, replace the # in the href="#" with whatever the webpage link is.

To make Home like the other buttons, remove class="current" from it.

Comment: This actually puts the links to the blocks before they do the animation. I need to know how to do it after the hover effect so the user can click on it.  Thank you for your input guys.

Comment: @NameFirst That's an error I can't seem to fix right now. But to explain why it's happening: the button is changing to whatever string is in the `data-hover`, switching from the link, to the string, therefore removing the link.

Comment: Im right there with you. I will put more time into figuring this out when I have it. Thanks for your help.